# Detecting a duration via NSDataDetector

Tags: objective-c, parsing, datetime, ios7, nsdatadetector

I'm trying to use [NSDataDetector](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/) to detect different data in strings. I noticed that when detecting a date (i.e. resultType is `NSTextCheckingTypeDate`), there are three valid properties:

- date
- duration
- timeZone

I was able to figure out how to create strings that produce a value for the date and timeZone, but I'm not sure which string will produce a value for duration.

For example, when I try parsing `12:15 UTC`, it populates the date and timeZone. I was thinking that something like `10 minutes` would produce a value for duration, but it doesn't even produce a match.

**Note**: `duration` should work according to [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/) and [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Notice how in the `NSTextCheckingResult` documentation, there is a section titled *Text Checking Results for Dates and Times* which mentions `duration`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get a duration if Data Detectors detects a date interval. For example with this string: "from December 10th at 2 to December 12th at 1"

and this logging code:

```
NSLog(@"Match: %@ (duration %g)", result, result.duration);
```

I get:

```
Match: <NSDateCheckingResult: 0x7fc2da810830>{0, 45}{2014-12-10 13:00:00 +0000-2014-12-12 12:00:00 +0000} (duration 169200)
```

(I'm in the UTC+1 timezone, this is why the hours are offset in the result)